# Inheritance and relationships between collections in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, typescript-typings, mongoose-schema

Using MongoDB/mongoose/typegoose and typesCript, I have some user , car and phone models where I need to have as an attribute of user, an array with the products (car and phone) that are related to it. You could use populate but you would need to make one for each product. It is not clear to me how inheritance is handled in MongoDB so that my project is scalable.